# Using OR in CASE to Resolve "Divide By Zero" Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a dynamic SQL which generated a SQL query for one of my calculation which resulted in a "***Divide by Zero***" error

Although I do have CASE statements to check for the error its not working for some reason.

Below is the calculation formula:

```
CASE WHEN SUM(A) = 0
     THEN 0
     WHEN SUM(B) = 0
     THEN 0
     ELSE
     SUM((C/B))/AVG(A) AS X
```

I am getting the error because column **B** has zero value in it.

Can you please help...

Comment: You are checking whether `SUM(A)` or `SUM(B)` is zero, but then you divide by every value of `B` and `AVG(A)`. You are not checking whether *any* value of `B` is zero, and you are not checking whether `AVG(A)` is zero.

Answer (score 3):

You could write it as simple as this and exclude the **CASE**:

```
ISNULL(SUM(C/NULLIF(B,0))/NULLIF(AVG(A),0),0) X
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using each value of `B`, not the `SUM(B)` as the divisor, you should be checking for the existence of `B` where `B = 0`. Same goes for `A`, you should check for `AVG(A)` instead of `SUM(A)`:

```
CASE 
    WHEN AVG(A) = 0 THEN 0
    WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN B = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 0
    ELSE SUM((C/B))/AVG(A)
END AS X
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to leave your existing checks in place, then you need to add extra checks like this. you need to make sure you dont have any `0` value for B. you may need to add where condition as per your requirement.

```
    CASE WHEN SUM(A) = 0
         THEN 0
         WHEN SUM(B) = 0
         THEN 0
         WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM  YOURTABLE WHERE B=0) -- add WHERE here if you need to.
         THEN 0
         WHEN AVG(A)=0
         THEN 0
         ELSE
         SUM((C/B))/AVG(A) 
   END AS X
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments and answers. Although both of the above answers didn't seem to work for some reason.

I ended-up using the snippet below to resolve the issue:

```
CASE 
    WHEN AVG(A) = 0 THEN 0
    ELSE ISNULL( SUM ((C/NULLIF(B,0)))/AVG(A),0)
END AS X
```